# value preserving across multiple pages

Tags: php

i am trying to post the some data on another page at this i have a back button onclick of back button i wanna reload the original page with posted data.

Answer (score 1):

use $_SESSION:

Page1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $name = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '';
?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="Page2.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['name']))
  {
     $_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['name']; 
  } 
  $name = $_SESSION['name'];
?>
<html>
<form>
   <span><?php echo $name; ?>" </span>
   <a href="page1.php">Back</a> 
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use $_SESSION

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

if ($_POST['btnsubmit']){
    $_SESSION['data1'] = $_POST['data1'];
    $_SESSION['data2'] = $_POST['data2'];
    $_SESSION['data3'] = $_POST['data3'];
    //... and so on
}
?>
<form>
<input type="text" id="data1" value="<? echo $_SESSION['data1'];?>"/>
<input type="text" id="data2" value="<? echo $_SESSION['data2'];?>"/>
<input type="text" id="data3" value="<? echo $_SESSION['data3'];?>"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
 <!-- and so on -->
```

Hope this gives you an idea